# Julia multiply 2 matrices in a for loop with a formula

Tags: for-loop, julia

Hello hopefully someone can help me... I am absolutely new to programming.

I just want to multiply two matrices in Julia with a for loop. It is about the frequency of a oscillation table at continuous casting in a steel plant. The below function calculates the frequency (=freqres) for a given mold stroke and casting speed(vc). The result is the frequency of the oscillation table for a given casting speed (from 1000mm/min to 6000mm/min).

```
vc = [1000:100:6000;]

function freqcalc(vc,stroke)
    for i in vc
        push!(freqres, 3i/4stroke)
    end
end
```

Now I want to calculate the negative strip time with the following formula:

```
nst = (60/(pi*freqres))*acos(vc/(pi*stroke*freqres))
```

With the below command I did not achieve the desired result, I think due to a nested condition.

```
nstres = Float64[]
for i in vc, j in freqres
    push!(nstres, (60/(pi*j))*acos(i/(pi*stroke*j)))
end
```

I just want to have the result of every entry of vc and freqres of the above formula in nstres.

```
push!(nstres, (60/(pi*freqres1))*acos(vc1/(pi*stroke*freqres1)))
push!(nstres, (60/(pi*freqres2))*acos(vc2/(pi*stroke*freqres2)))
```

I hope I could clarify my question, and thanks for your comments, I very appreciate it.

Comment: Hello, @kenspa, could you write desired calculation in mathematical form?

Comment: It's very unclear what you want to do. What is "the nested condition"? What is the value of `stroke`? What does "filling lines in the nesters" mean?

Comment: are you looking for the [`zip`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/iterators/#Base.Iterators.zip) function ?